# How to control Kurento audio recorder quality

Tags: audio, kurento

We recently built a demo application utilizing Kurento Media Server to record applicant video interview, but the audio quality is not well , some audio is not recognizable and some of it had high pitch noise. We've been test it on several models of PC or Mac, so this should not be device problem.

We've been using RecorderEndpoint with media profile MediaProfileSpecType.WEBM ,and all other setting remain as default.

To fix this problem, we tried:

1. We upgrade to Kurento 6.2.1 which use Opus as the audio encoder.
2. Try to using setMaxOuputBitrate of the recorder, we don't see it has improvements or I don't know which bit rate range can be used.
3. Change SDPOffer to setup a high bit rate audio for Opus which we don't know where to modify

None of it is working so far, so please tell us where to look.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you make sure that indeed the audio is being sent by the browser with good quality? You can test that with a loopback, plugin headphones to your box.

Comment: if audio sent by browser is the key to the problem, is there anyway to enhance the sample rate for webrtc audio? Yes, with headphones, the quality has limited improvements.

Comment: You can also check with this [online demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/), just to be sure it's how the media is being sent from the browser. Please check with FF and Chrome. Don't know if there is any way to improve the audio encoding capabilities of the browser. You'll have to check in Chrome and FF forums. It would be interesting, though, as there are other users that have found the same limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with [this](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-hello-world-recording) recording tutorial. The audio should be fine. Just make sure you are only sending audio, and not video. That should help.

If the audio is not being recorded correctly, I would try and hear what's coming out of your box through your browser. Try and run the hello-world tutorial, with a pair of headphones connected to your box so you don't have echoes.

About #2, if you want to raise the bitrate exchanged between the webrtc endpoint and the recorder, you need to invoke the `setOutputBitrate` command on the webrtc endpoint.